# How to have a link in a FancyTree

Tags: javascript, php, yii, fancytree

I try to use a fancytree. everything is displayed correctly but I can't have a link on the text of the node... why ? and how to solve that?

I tried to put html link like this :

```
 <div id="tree">    
    <ul>
        <li><a href="..."> My Link to view 1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="..."> My Link to view 2 </a>
            <ul>
                 <li><a href="..." > My link to view 2, 1st object </a></li>
                 <li><a href="..." > My link to view 2, 2nd object </a></li>
                 ...
            </ul>
        </li>
        ...
    <ul>
 </div>
```

Or I tried with

```
<li Onclick="clickEntite(\''.Yii::app()->CreateAbsoluteUrl($axe['id_entite'].'/view',array('id'=>$axe['id_entite'])).'\')" >'.$axe['text'].'</li>


  <script type="text/javascript">
function clickEntite(url){
    window.location.href=url;       
};
  </script>
```

without any success.

It seems that FancyTree delete all link on his node.

Is it possible to redirect to the right view when a node becomes active or when the checkbox is checked?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have link on a node there are several option in the plugin.

redirect when it is focused, ativated or clicked.

here is the code I found for the different options.  (I use the activate one)

```
        focus: function(event, data) {
            var node = data.node;
            // Auto-activate focused node after 1 second
            if(node.data.href){
                node.scheduleAction("activate", 1000);
            }
        },

        activate: function(event, data){
            var node = data.node,
                orgEvent = data.originalEvent;

            if(node.data.href){
                //window.open(node.data.href, (orgEvent.ctrlKey || orgEvent.metaKey) ? "_blank" /*node.data.target*/ : node.data.target);
                window.location.href=node.data.href;    
            }
        },

        click: function(event, data){ // allow re-loads
            var node = data.node,
                orgEvent = data.originalEvent;

            if(node.isActive() && node.data.href){
                // data.tree.reactivate();
                window.open(node.data.href, (orgEvent.ctrlKey || orgEvent.metaKey) ? "_blank" : node.data.target);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks like that is pretty much just http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-iframe.html

Comment: Using the same approach as Vincent worked like a charm (except that I have  Backbone.JS app, so used Backbone Navigation instead). Thanks!